# Customized 404 page on yahoo webhosting

Tags: yahoo, web-hosting

I want to add my customized 404 error page. On Apache server an entry made in .htaccess file does this task.I have my website on yahoo web hosting. 
Yahoo does not support .htaccess file. 
Can anyone please guide how this can be achieved on yahoo web hosting.

Answer (score 4):

From http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/webhosting/editors/editors-16.html

> To create your own custom error page, you'll simply need to build a
>   page using any of our tools and save the page in your main directory
>   with the name e404.html (for "404 not found" errors) or e401.html (for
>   "401 authorization required" errors).

Answer (score -1):

You can meta refresh from this page to a custom PHP error page

Comment: The server will not be returning the appropriate 404 header if a document containing a meta refresh is returned first.